# Get Left, Right, Up, Down Nonzero Neighbor from SciPy Sparse Matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

Say that I have a 2D SciPy Sparse Matrix:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csc_matrix

arr = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
                [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
               ])

csc = csc_matrix(arr)
```

For each nonzero element within the matrix, I'd like to create four new sparse matrices that contain the index corresponding to the next nearest Left, Right, Up, and Down nonzero neighbor. The elements at the ends can have neighbors that are wrapped around (think circular doubly linked list in both the horizontal and vertical directions or toroidal). In the case where an element is the only nonzero element in its row/column then the corresponding index will point to itself. Additionally, since the indices can have a zero value (when referencing the first row or column) and be indistinguishable from the naturally zero elements, we set these zero indices to -1 in order to disambiguate a real index from the zero elements.

For the matrix above, the dense Left and Down matrices would look like:

```
left = np.array([[0, 0, 4,  0, 2],
                 [3, 0, 0, -1, 0],
                 [0, 2, 1,  0, 0],
                 [3, 0, 0, -1, 0],
                 [0, 1, 0,  0, 0],
                ])

down = np.array([[0, 0,  2, 0, -1],
                 [3, 0,  0, 3,  0],
                 [0, 4, -1, 0,  0],
                 [1, 0,  0, 1,  0],
                 [0, 2,  0, 0,  0],
                ])
```

Remember that elements with an index value of -1 are actually references to index zero. Of course, I need to have these matrices in sparse matrix form as my real matrices are too large and sparse to fit into memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible way to do the left neighbor one. 
It's not particularly efficient, but probably works okay if there are't a lot of nonzero entries in the whole matrix. You can optimize it slightly by getting the nonzero entries of each row as you go and only computing `j[i==row]` once.

Note that I just shift the indices up by one rather than setting `0` to `-1`.

```
i,j = csc.nonzero()
ind = sp.sparse.csc_matrix(csc.shape,dtype='int')
for row in range(csc.shape[0]):
    ind[row,j[i==row]] = np.roll(j[i==row]+1,1)

ind.A = array([[0, 0, 5, 0, 3],
   [4, 0, 0, 1, 0],
   [0, 3, 2, 0, 0],
   [4, 0, 0, 1, 0],
   [0, 2, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: I thought `np.roll` produces a dense matrix?

Comment: `np.roll` is applied to an array of indices of nonzero entries.

Comment: Ahhhh, interesting. That just might work! I wonder if we even need to add one to the indices as long as we don't call `eliminate_zeros` on the sparse array. Of course, it becomes confusing when we convert it to dense...

Comment: Initializing `ind` with `sparse.lil_matrix` may be faster, and avoid the efficiency warning.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [183]: arr = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
     ...:                 [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
     ...:                 [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
     ...:                 [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
     ...:                 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
     ...:                ])
     ...:                
In [184]: from scipy import sparse
In [185]: M = sparse.lil_matrix(arr)
In [186]: M.rows
Out[186]: 
array([list([2, 4]), list([0, 3]), list([1, 2]), list([0, 3]), list([1])],
      dtype=object)
```

That's the same information as you'd get from a dense array with:

```
In [187]: [np.where(row)[0] for row in arr]
Out[187]: [array([2, 4]), array([0, 3]), array([1, 2]), array([0, 3]), array([1])]
```

I assume you have already figured out how to generate the desired `left` (or `right`) from a dense array, so I won't get into those details (I'm too lazy to wrestle with your wrapping specifications).

For columns:

```
 In [189]: M.T.rows
 Out[189]: 
 array([list([1, 3]), list([2, 4]), list([0, 2]), list([1, 3]), list([0])],
  dtype=object)
```

From the `csc` format you can use:

```
In [190]: Mc = sparse.csc_matrix(arr)
In [191]: Mc.indptr
Out[191]: array([0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9], dtype=int32)
In [192]: Mc.indices
Out[192]: array([1, 3, 2, 4, 0, 2, 1, 3, 0], dtype=int32)
In [193]: for i in range(5):
     ...:     print(Mc.indices[Mc.indptr[i]:Mc.indptr[i+1]])
     ...:     
[1 3]
[2 4]
[0 2]
[1 3]
[0]
```

In this example all rows or columns have only 1 or 2 nonzeros.  I suppose in a larger more general one there will be many nonzeros.  Also with `csc` (and `csr` there's the possibility that indices per 'row' are not sorted - there's a sparse method to address that.

As for building the return sparse matrix, you could modify the `data` attribute of a copy (it will have the same sparsity).

```
In [194]: M.data
Out[194]: 
array([list([1, 1]), list([1, 1]), list([1, 1]), list([1, 1]), list([1])],
      dtype=object)
In [195]: Mc.data
Out[195]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int64)
```

Or construct a sparse matrix from arrays (as is normal for `coo` style input).

---

With my `lil` version, `tch's` solution is modestly faster:

```
ind = sparse.lil_matrix(M.shape,dtype='int')
for i,row in enumerate(M.rows):
    k = np.array(row)
    ind[i,k] = np.roll(k+1,1)
```

Even better with my idea of replacing the `data`:

```
ind = M.copy()
for row,dat in zip(ind.rows,ind.data):
    k = np.array(row)
    dat[:] = np.roll(k+1,1).tolist()
```

Or with `Mr = Mc.tocsr()`

```
ind = Mr.copy()
for i in range(Mr.shape[0]):
    slc = slice(Mr.indptr[i],Mr.indptr[i+1])
    k = Mr.indices[slc]
    ind.data[slc] = np.roll(k+1,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer (dense form):

```
ix, iy = csc.nonzero()
w = np.where(np.insert(np.diff(ix), 0,1) != 0)[0]
iy2 = np.concatenate([np.roll(_, 1) for _ in np.split(iy,w)])
iy2[iy2==0] = -1

left = csc_matrix(arr.shape)
left[ix, iy] = iy2

ix, iy = csc.transpose().nonzero()
w = np.where(np.insert(np.diff(ix), 0,1) != 0)[0]
iy2 = np.concatenate([np.roll(_, 1) for _ in np.split(iy,w)])
iy2[iy2==0] = -1

down = csc_matrix(arr.T.shape)
down[ix, iy] = iy2
down = down.transpose()
print(left.todense(), '\n', down.todense())


 >> [[ 0  0  4  0  2]
 [ 3  0  0 -1  0]
 [ 0  2  1  0  0]
 [ 3  0  0 -1  0]
 [ 0  1  0  0  0]]

[[ 0  0  2  0 -1]
 [ 3  0  0  3  0]
 [ 0  4 -1  0  0]
 [ 1  0  0  1  0]
 [ 0  2  0  0  0]]
```

Comment: I thought `np.roll` produces a dense matrix? I need the intermediate data to be in sparse format as well as the final matrix also needs to be sparse.

Comment: I edited the answer. Essentially, what I'm proposing is you only work over the non-zero indices in dense form, roll them, then place them in a bigger matrix in sparse form. The non-zero indices (IMO) can be worked in dense form since they represent only a small part of your original matrix

Answer (score 0):

A more vectored approach :

```
csc = csc_matrix(arr)
inds = (csc.indices,csc.indptr)
irows = np.split(*inds)[1:-1]

down = csc_matrix((np.hstack([np.roll(row,-1) for row in irows]),*inds))
up = csc_matrix((np.hstack([np.roll(row,1) for row in irows]),*inds))
```

Check :

```
>>> down.A 
array([[0, 0, 2, 0, 0],
       [3, 0, 0, 3, 0],
       [0, 4, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 2, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

Left and Right can be obtained with the CSR representation.

I don' think coding 0 by -1 is a good idea, since if will break all sparse computation improvement. only places designed by `csc.nonzeros()` must be visited.